# The probability that a run of $n$ consecutive successes occurs in a sequence of $2^n$ Bernoulli trials.

Tags: probability

Let $c_j$ be the event that $n$ successes occurs in the position $j$.
So clearly I'm looking for $P\{\bigcup_{j=1}^{2^n - n}  c_j \}$
But I don't know how can I compute this.
Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried inclusion and exclusion?

Comment: is this any occurrence of a run of n exactly or any occurrence of a run of n or more

Comment: the book I've got does both, it's 'probability by James Gray'  He uses a recurrence relationship

Comment: @Cato is any occurrence of a n or more. I'll check the book, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_m$ denote the number of 0-1-sequences of length $m$ without a run of $n$ consecutive 1's. Clearly, $a_m=2^m$ for $0\le m<n$. For larger $m$, such a sequence ends in a string of the form $01^j$ with $0\le j<n$ and before that comes an arbitrary sequence of length $m-j-1$ without a run of $n$ consecutive 1's. That is
$$ \tag1a_m=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{m-j}\qquad\text{for }m\ge n.$$
Then the desired probability is
$$ p=1-\frac{a_{2^n}}{2^{2^n}}.$$
This allows us to numerically compute $p=p(n)$ for small $n$.
For example
$$\begin{array}tn&p\\1&\frac34\\
2&\frac12\\3&\frac{107}{256}&\approx0.417969\\
4&\frac{809}{2048}&\approx 0.398915\\
5&\frac{418289307}{1073741824}&\approx 0.389562\\
6&&\approx 0.389292\\
7&&\approx 0.390277\\8&&\approx 0.391316
\end{array} $$
Interestingly, the $p(n)$ first decreases, then increases.

For larger $n$, we will only go for an estimate.
Consider the polynomial $f(X)=X^n-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}X^j$ as well as $g(X)=(X-1)f(X)=(X-2)X^n+1$. If $u,v,\lambda\in \Bbb R_{>0}$ with $f(\lambda)=0$ and $u\lambda ^m\le a_m\le v\lambda^m$ for $0\le m<n$, then it follows from $(1)$ by induction that this bound holds for all $m\ge n$ as well and ultimately $$1-v(\lambda/2)^{2^n}\le p\le 1-u(\lambda/2)^{2^n}.$$
Remains to find $u,v,\lambda$.
Using Bernoulli,
$$1-n\epsilon\le (1-\epsilon)^n\le\frac1{(1+\epsilon)^n}\le\frac1{1+n\epsilon}\qquad \text{for }0\le\epsilon<1.$$
Thus  for $0\le t\le4^n$ by,
  $$g(2-t2^{-n})=-t2^{-n}(2-t2^{-n})^n+1
=1-t(1-t2^{-2n})^n\begin{cases}\le 1-t(1-nt2^{-2n})\\
\ge1-\frac t{1+nt2^{-2n}}\end{cases}$$
For $t=1+(n+1)2^{-2n}$ and $n\ge3$ (so that $(n+1)\le 2^{n-1}$) the upper bound is $$-2^{-2n}+n(n+1)2^{1-4n}+n(n+1)^22^{-6n}<-2^{-2n}+2^{-2n-1}+2^{-3n-3}<0,$$
whereas for $t=1+n2^{-2n}$, the lower bound is
$$1-\frac {1+n2^{-2n}}{1+n2^{-2n}+n^22^{-4n}}>0.$$
We conclude that $f(\lambda)=0$ for some $\lambda$ with
$$ 2-2^{-n}-(n+1)2^{-3n}<\lambda<2-2^{-n}-n2^{-3n}.$$
As $\lambda<2$, we can simply take $u=1$ and from
$$\frac{\lambda^n}{2^n}>(1-2^{-1-n}-(n+1)2^{-3n-1})^n>1-n2^{-1-n}-n(n+1)2^{-3n-1} $$
we see that we can take $v=\frac1{1-n2^{-1-n}-n(n+1)2^{-3n-1}}\approx1+n2^{-1-n}$.

In the limit as $n\to\infty$, we see that $\frac\lambda2$ is close enough to $1-\frac1{2^{n+1}}$ to conclude that $$ 1-p\approx \left(1-\frac1{2^{n+1}}\right)^{2^n}=\sqrt{\left(1-\frac1{2^{n+1}}\right)^{2^{n+1}}}\approx \sqrt e.$$

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} p(n) = 1 - e^{-1/2} \approx 0.3934$.  This follows from Proposition V.1 in Flajolet and Sedgewick, Analytic Combinatorics (http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf), with some changes of variable.  I wonder if there's a "nice" way to see that the correlation means that $-1/2$ should replace $-1$ in the exponent.